# Past Simple or Past Perfect?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

Which is grammatically correct?

> He woke up late this morning because he had a party with his friends last night.

Or

> He woke up late this morning because he had had a party with his friends last night.

Answer (score 1):

Since "last night" seems to actually refer the night before the utterance of the sentence (because we read "this morning" rather than "that morning"), both versions are correct and mean more or less the same thing. If the party and the apparent hangover episode the speaker speaks of had happened earlier, then one would normally use the past perfect:

> He woke up late *that* morning since he had had a party with his friends *the night before*.

Comment: I agree entirely.

Comment: If this were speech or informal writing, I'd recommend the first version, failing that  the contracted form: "... since he'd had a party the night before".